# Can't post via notification center

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, facebook, notifications

I have integrated both twitter and facebook account to my macbook-pro. I am getting notifications perfectly. The only problem I have is that I can't post via notification center. There're 2 buttons `Click to post`, one each for twitter and facebook, which used to work fine previously. Now suddenly they stopped responding. When I click on them nothing happens. I can see click animation(pushing of button), but it does nothing, no edit area to post my updates, nothing at all.

How can I get the functionality back?

Comment: Have you tried removing and resetting the integrazion?

Comment: Thanks for responding. How do I remove it, by disabling it in notification center or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to repair permissions.

If that doesn’t work, try installing the [latest combo update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1581?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) again. This will most likely fix your issue.

If even that doesn’t solve the problem, reinstall OS X and then install the latest update **without removing your current installation**. Just install it on top of the current installation. You won’t have to mess with backing up/restoring and you will fix all issues.

Comment: Well I've installed the combo update, but nothing changed. I don't know how can I repair permissions. Reinstalling a complete OS just for a minor bug, doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Google “how to repair permissions”. And did you install the combo update **again**?

Comment: repaired the permissions, still the same issue persists. And yeah I've reinstalled it the update.

Comment: Create a new test user and see if the problem persists. If not, reset your home directory permissions and ACLs (Google how to do that). If yes, then a reinstall of OS X is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Solved following this guide. You simply have to kill the notification center process.

http://n8henrie.com/2012/08/fix-click-to-tweet-in-mountain-lion-notification-center/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove and re-set the integration?

1. Go to *System Preferences* > *Mail, Contacts & Calendars*
2. Select your Facebook account on the left
3. Press the button `-`

The same for twitter.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Same problem. The click doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Download the combo update from ... http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1581

Don't forget the supplemental update too ... http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1600

NOTE: As a rule, I never use Software Update for OS updates. I find manually downloading and installing the Combo Update (not the incremental one) .. eliminates a lot of headaches.